# Updated Reputation tab displays dates incorrectly

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, reputation-history

It must be a recent update, but I've just noticed that on the Reputation tab the dates are displayed incorrectly. For example, instead of `12 secs ago` it says `12 secs agoprettyDec 7`

[image]

It seems to be working fine with `yesterday`, or `n days ago` though:

[image]

Comment: Already reported: [New responsive Activity page](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/372604/289905).

Comment: I haven't noticed that thread, thanks.